# Sequential numbering on file name (Continue numbering on multiple commands)

Tags: command-line, bash

I'm encoding multiple music videos to HEVC and backing them up on `1fichier` using `rclone`. Since these are small files (100 MB on average) and when I upload them in bulk I get a `Flood detected: IP Locked` error from  `1fichier`, I zip 10 files and upload. This way it is more convenient and easier to download later.

I have an alias for this code and run it once in while:

```
cd ~/ffmpeg && mkdir music && ls -Q hevc | head -10 | xargs -i mv hevc/{} music/ \
&& mv music ~/downloads/music && cd ~/downloads && du -sh music && \
zip -r music.zip music && rm -r music && \
rclone move ~/downloads/ 1fichier:musiczip -P --transfers=1
```

The problem is that I have to manually rename the files in `1fichier` sequentially. Is there any way to sequentially number the zip files, for example `music001.zip`, before uploading them?

I'm thinking of something like:

```
mv music.zip music$NUM.zip
```

Please note that this command will be run at different times not continuously.

**Update** : I simplified the above command if anyone is interested:

```
ls | grep .mkv | head -10 | zip -@ -m -v music.zip
```

This will zip first 10 mkv files in the currect directory.

```
cd ~/ffmpeg && mkdir music && ls -Q hevc | head -10 | xargs -i mv hevc/{} music/ \
    && mv music ~/downloads/music && cd ~/downloads && du -sh music && \
    zip -r music.zip music && rm -r music
```

This is was the previous command.

**Update - 2** : On `1fichier` `Flood detected: IP Locked` can be avoided by transferring files one by one. While using the command `rclone move` append `--transfers=1` (Default is 3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the last used number in a file, say `lastnum`, then read it each time and increment it. In bash:

```bsh
[ ! -f lastnum ] && echo 0 >lastnum
num=$(<lastnum)
let num=num+1
echo $num >lastnum
num=$(printf "%03d" $num)
echo "... using music$num.zip"
```

Comment: Trying to implement this, thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the command in your alias to this:

```
cd ~/ffmpeg && mkdir music && ls -Q hevc | head -10 | xargs -i mv hevc/{} music/ && mv music ~/downloads/music && cd ~/downloads && du -sh music && zip -r music"$(date +%s)".zip music && rm -r music && rclone move ~/downloads/ 1fichier:musiczip -P --transfers=1
```

`zip -r music"$(date +%s)".zip music` will add **time in seconds since epoch** to the name of the created ZIP archive and it will look something like this:

```
music1611590629.zip
```

And it would have a unique name each time you run the command.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I can use this in another similar scenario where sequential numbering is becoming messed up.